# A question about Infimum.

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be an infinite set that includes Real numbers and its not bounded. Let $B$ be a set of Real numbers $x$ s.t. the intersection $A\cap[x,\infty)$ is $empty$ or includes $finite$ number of elements.

- prove or disprove the existence of $\inf B$  if $A$ is not bounded.

Actually this is the third part of the question that I didn't solve. I think there is more than one situation in this case. can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: What is the difference with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000340/question-about-two-sets? Or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001474/question-about-infimum-conclusion-about-intersection? If you are understanding the given solutions you should be able to get the answer.

Comment: the answer is wrong in the previous question, and I couldn't delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A=\{-n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=A.$

Comment: in this case the infimum of B = - infinity ?

Comment: I would say that the infimum doesn't exist. The infimum is the greatest lower bound and there is no any lower bound.

Comment: yeah, I got you. that means this is an example where we disprove that B has an infimum. but it doesn't mean that in other cases it hasn't. right?

Comment: is there any example where i can disprove the nonexistence of infimum?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. We have given an example where the infimum doesn't exists. Do you mean an example where the infimum exists?

Comment: yeah, disprove the nonexistence = proving existence. little word game.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Notice that $A$ being bounded means that there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ a positive number s.t. $A \subset (-M,M)$, which implies that $A \cap [M,+\infty)= \emptyset$. Try to solve it from there.

Comment: I solved the questions that deal with A being bounded, but now what happens if its not?

Comment: being not bounded in this case means that from one side it can be bounded and the other side it can continue to infinity.

Comment: Well, you can always think of an example where $A$ is not bounded. Take $A=\mathbb{Z} \cap (-\infty,0]$, for example. You will find that for every real $x$, the set $A \cap [x,+\infty)$ is finite, which means $B=\mathbb{R}$ and then, there is no infimum. That disproves the existence of the infimum. With another counter example, you can disprove the inexistance too, meaning that both cases might happen, it just depends on the $A$ given.

Comment: is there any example where i can disprove the nonexistence of infimum? ( this is the hard part for me)

Comment: Take $A=(-\infty,0]$. $A$ is not bounded and $B=[0,+\infty)$, wich means that $infB = 0$. So in this case, the infimum exists, disproving it's inexistence for all $A$ unbounded.

Comment: but in this case its not called infB, its minB because the infimum is included in B. Im thinking about the real definition of infimum.

Comment: But $\min B$ can be $\inf B$. The definition of $\inf B$ is a real number $x$ s.t. $y \in B \implies x \leq y$ and given a lower quota $m$ for $B$, $m \leq x$. This definition does not require it to be outside $B$. It is also equivalent to $\inf B = x$ is defined as a real number s.t. $y \in B \implies x \leq y$ and $\forall \epsilon >0\ \  \exists y \in B \cap [x, \epsilon)$. This last definition is better for proving other things and solving problems and exercises. Its good to remember that it only always exists in $\mathbb{R}$. In $\mathbb{Q}$, it might not exists for some sets.